# Rewrite a url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am completely new to ht-access and I am not sure that this is the correct way to do this.
On my WordPress site, I have the current url:
http://www.example.com/category/travel/

And would like to map this to:
http://www.example.com/kids-vaction-spots/

So any post under the category travel would look like:
www.example.com/kids-vaction-spots/beach-holidays

Is it possible to have a rule in the htaccess that does this?

Thank you for taking the time to look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root. Make sure they're above any rules that do routing for a CMS.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?category/travel/(.*)$ /kids-vacation-spots/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you that works, however I get a page not found now.
It directs my category archive to http://www.example.com/kids-vaction-spots/ which is what I wanted to see in the address bar, but the archive is not displayed.

Do I have to change my permalinks inside wordpress, or am I trying to do something that is not possible here?